# Retrieve cost on certain date SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have the following tables:

- Order (orderID, date, shipID)
- Shipping (shipID, price)
- PO (prodID, orderID, amount)
- Price (prodID, fromDate, price)

I need to retrieve each order ID and the total price including the cost of the items in order + the cost of shipping purchased. The cost of the item has to be the cost of the item on the order date, not the most recent date. The Price table stores the different prices of a product starting at a particular date (fromDate attribute). Hence, the price of a product on day d is the price in the entry with the largest fromDate-value f such that f ≤ d. I understand I can use the command max(fromDate) to retrieve the latest price on an item, however, I cannot figure out how to get the price on a certain date. This is my code so far:

```
SELECT o.orderId, SUM(pr.price) + SUM(s.price) orderCost
FROM "Order" o 
INNER JOIN Shipping s
ON o.shipId = s.shipId
INNER JOIN PO po
ON po.orderId = o.orderId
INNER JOIN Price pr
ON pr.prodId = po.prodId
GROUP BY  o.orderId;
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
select o.orderId, SUM(pr.price) + SUM(s.price) orderCost
from [Order] o 
INNER JOIN Shipping s ON o.shipId = s.shipId
inner join PO po on o.shipId   = po.shipId 
inner join (select top 1 price from Price pr where fromDate = (select max(fromDate)from Price pr where fromDate <= [date])) pr 
on pr.prodID  = po.prodID
GROUP BY  o.orderId;
```